# Angularjs v1.3.15 - Webkit Text Color Rendering Bug on Pageload

Tags: css, angularjs, webkit

It seems like overriding text colors (blue in this case) aren't being used/recognized until a user either hovers over the text or resizes the window.

[image: example 1]

I thought I fixed this situation by changed the `transition` property so it's set on hover/active like so:

```
.grey-tab {
  .transition(none);
  &:hover, &.active {
    .transition(all .2s ease);
  }
}
```

But, after lots of clicking, it's still broken.  In the past, I have used a [terrible solution](https://gist.github.com/mattnish/0d14893cfd4eb2ee967e) to fix the issue, by applying a delayed CSS3 transform to the text, which triggers a redraw.  But I'd like to fix the real problem, as this keeps popping up in Angular projects.

Twitter conversation regarding issue:
https://twitter.com/KMuncie/status/573583334703521793

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Chrome v41.0.2272.101

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using `ng-href` alone is the issue.  There's 2 solutions to this rendering issue:

- Use `ng-href` with a blank `href="#"` or...
- Use only `href` (which is against ng conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Nish's href="#" solution didn't work for me, and I don't want to use href, nor the display-hack keyframe.

My `<a>` tags were black in Safari, instead of grey. Using a `<span>` tag inside the `<a>` fixed the issue for me.